# How to display the same views exposed form block twice?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I'm trying to display the same views exposed from block twice. Once in the left nav and once in content top. With multi block I can clone the block and I am able to display both. However, I would like the left nav form to have less exposed filters.

The problem is that in `hook_form_alter()` and `hook_preprocess_views_exposed_from()` there are no unique identifiers that I can check to alter the form. It runs through the hooks twice but I cannot seem to know if I am dealing with the left nav form or the content top form.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

I tried the code below which works for views 2 and was going to create my own block and render the form. But I cannot get the code to work for views 3.

```
$view = views_get_view('brands');
$view->set_display('page_2');
$view->init_handlers();

$form_state = array(
  'view' => $view,
  'display' => $view->display_handler->display,
  'method' => 'get',
  'rerender' => TRUE,
  'no_redirect' => TRUE,
);

$output = drupal_build_form('views_exposed_form', $form_state);
$blocks['content'] = $output;
```

Am I looking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me. I'm using Views 6 Alpha 4.

```
$view = views_get_view('your_view');
$view->set_display('the_display_you_want_that_have_a_exposed_block');
$view->init_handlers();
$exposed_form = $view->display_handler->get_plugin('exposed_form');
print $exposed_form->render_exposed_form(true);
```

Comment: This works for D7 V3 as well

Answer (score 2):

1> Can't you add one more display of the same view and override filters for that display? If I get your question correctly then that should do it, you want 2 diff versions of exposed filters in block from a view.

Suggestion for multi block problem:

2> I would rather use context module - http://drupal.org/project/context to deal with multiple same blocks on the same page and other block visibility issues. This prolly won't solve the current problem at hand but is a better practice going fwd compared to multi block and block clone strategies.

Comment: That is definitely plan b. What I'm trying to avoid is having 2 views that do the exact same query. I would prefer for potential future growth to have only one point of management. However, having a different display in the same view isn't that bad. I wanted to see if anyone has discovered a clever way to accomplish this. I also prefer context. It's the most highly used module in our office. The context add assets module birth place was in our office.

Answer (score 0):

I use some different code to create a block with a views form in (for a different reason, to display the form as a page callback, but it should still work).

```
 $module = 'views';
 $delta = '-exp-my_block_id';
 $block = (object) module_invoke($module, 'block', 'view', $delta);
 $block->module = $module;
 $block->delta = $delta;
 return theme('block', $block);
```